# ServerSocket y Socket java

Tags: java, socket

```
class ClienteFecha {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String servidor = "localhost";
        int puerto = 13;             // puerto de daytime

        try {
            // Se abre un socket conectado al servidor y al
            // puerto estándar de echo
            Socket socket = new Socket( servidor,puerto );
            System.out.println( "Socket Abierto." );

            // Se consigue el canal de entrada
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );

            System.out.println( "Hora actual en localhost:" );
            System.out.println( "\t"+entrada.readLine() );
            System.out.println( "Hora actual con la clase date:" );
            System.out.println( "\t" + new Date() );

            // Se cierra el canal de entrada
            entrada.close();

            // Se cierra el socket
            socket.close();
        } catch( UnknownHostException e ) {
            System.out.println( e );
            System.out.println("Debes estar conectado para que esto funcione bien." );
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( e );
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("estoy después de crear el socket");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("estoy después de aceptar un cliente");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();

        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
            out.println(outputLine);
            if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Al tener las dos clases de arriba(o cualquier ejemplo referido a sockets también sirve para mi pregunta),

- **¿Que código se ejecuta primero?**
- **¿Que sucede si el servidor ejecuta mas rápido el código y lee la instrucción `in.readLine()` antes de que mi cliente haya enviado los
  datos?**

La pregunta en general sería, 
**¿Como se asegura mi servidor de que primero recibe los datos y después lee/revisa la entrada?**

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Que sucede si el servidor ejecuta mas rápido el código y lee la instrucción `in.readLine()` antes de que mi cliente haya enviado los datos? (...) ¿Como se asegura mi servidor de que primero recibe los datos y después lee/revisa la entrada?

Cuando abres un `ServerSocket` para atender una petición de un cliente, es decir, cuando utilizas [`ServerSocket#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--), la aplicación se "paraliza" para escuchar a un cliente y continuará su ejecución cuando un cliente se conecte. Esto se explica en la documentación del método (énfasis mía):

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. **The method blocks until a connection is made.**

Traducido a español (énfasis mía):

> Se escucha por una conexión hecha a este socket y la acepta. **El método se bloquea hasta que se realice una conexión.**

Por ende si ejecutas la clase servidor y no ejecutas el cliente, la aplicación servidor se paralizará hasta que se conecte un cliente.

Luego, el `InputStream` devuelto por `Socket#getInputStream` va a delegar las operaciones de lectura al canal asociado al socket cliente. Dependiendo del protocolo de red utilizado, estas operaciones pueden ser o no bloqueantes. Para tu caso, estas operaciones son bloqueantes, es decir, mientras el cliente no escriba ningún dato en su `OutputStream`, el servidor no podrá leer información del cliente.

Comment: Claro, pero cuando ya aceptó la conexión y el cliente y el servidor siguen con sus códigos, no puede llegar a ejecutarse primero el readLine del servidor?

Comment: @MatiEzelQ por favor considera la edición que he hecho en mi respuesta.

Comment: Eso no entendía, muuchas gracias Luiggi